# Launch IDLE (python 3.9) from start menu

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle, msix

currently we have an MSIX package deployed for python 3.9 on Windows 10 via app attach (vhd stage and register).

[image: MSIX package deployed via app attach]
Everything works fine except the IDLE interpreter. Currently as a workaround we can call it via cmd using the python shell.

[image: Call IDLE via python shell]

However if we try to run it from start menu, nothing happens.

[image: IDLE doesn't launch from start menu]

We tried defining the system path environment variables for the same while creating the MSIX package (C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\idlelib) but no success.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what target is set to your IDLE start menu shortcut? Where does it point to?

Comment: Hi Bogdan, as per local installation it point out to  "C:\Program Files\Python39\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw" , further checking on the App manifest for the MSIX package it points to "VFS\ProgramFilesX64\Python39\pythonw.exe"